# Cannot resolve symbol errors Android Studio

Tags: android

I am getting the error "cannot resolve symbol" on fragment_container and CrimeFragment. I am very new to Android Studio so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is Crime_Fragment.java**

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // This space intentionally left blank
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // This one too
            }
        });

      mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM F, yyyy.");
        mDateButton.setText(sdf.format(mCrime.getDate()));
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // Set the crime's solved property
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Here is activity_crime.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Where is CrimeFragment?

Comment: Located withing the if statement ---------> fragment = new CrimeFragment();

Comment: Please post the error log. Have you add support v4 and v7 in your project?

Comment: @isnotmenow This is clearly not the problem. The errors occur on the OPs own identifiers.

Comment: Check `activity_crime.xml  ` for errors.

Comment: Also please post `CrimeFragment.java ` and `activity_crime.xml `.

Comment: I found an error in activity_crime.xml that took care of the issue with fragment_container.  However, CrimeFragment is still in error